# Joining tables and applying functions to columns with the same name in R and tidyverse

Tags: r, join, dplyr, left-join

I am looking to join tables with customer id (easy enough) but then I want to multiply the columns to get updated values.

```
Customer_Week_1<-data.frame(First_name=c("John","Mary","David","Paul"),
                            Last_name=c("Jackson","Smith","Williams", "Zimmerman"),
                            Factor_1=c(2,5,8,9),
                            Factor_2=c(.5,.5,.75,.75),
                            Factor_3=c(0,1,2,3))
Customer_Week_2<-data.frame(First_name=c("John","Mary","David","Paul"),
                            Last_name=c("Jackson","Smith","Williams", "Zimmerman"),
                            Factor_1=c(3,7,1,7),
                            Factor_2=c(.51,.65,.72,.4),
                            Factor_3=c(1,2,3,4))

Customer_week3<-Customer_Week_1%>%
  left_join(Customer_Week_2, by = c("First_name","Last_name"))
```

The expected results can be found by in a vector by just

```
Customer_week3_expected<-Customer_Week_1[,3:5]*Customer_Week_2[,3:5]
```

And I know I can just manually type out every column. But I have dozens of columns and need to make this code as easy to follow as possible.

I also know that I can just bind the results vector to

```
Customer_week3<-Customer_Week_1%>%
  left_join(Customer_Week_2, by = c("First_name","Last_name"))%>%
  select(1:2)
```

But that does not look like best practice to me, and I would rather this be done with a join some way to ensure everything lines up when I am iterating over the customers(tables)

Comment: Thanks for the quick edit to make it readable Jilber. I pushed "post" too soon by accident. But thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have dozens of columns"? How would those columns affect this calculation?

Comment: @avid_useR I only mean that I have about 27 tables each with 8 or 9 columns (factors) that need to be lined up and multiplied with the coding. So lining up "Factor_1" for each table and then Factor_2 : Factor_8, and then all of that 27 times is a lot of code that the end user wont be able to follow easily.

Comment: These answers do get the job done, so I am grateful. However, I was hoping I could do this without simply binding. I get nervous calculating and then binding. Always afraid the rows will not line up in the same order. Even though I know that is probably not a rational fear. Thanks to all who looked into this for me/us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand the output you're trying to get, I can think of two methods. If you know that the names are in the first two columns and are the same in both data frames (this might not be the case in real life), you can use the same multiplication operation you tried above, bound to the first two columns of either of the data frames.

```r
cbind(Customer_Week_1[1:2], Customer_Week_1[-1:-2] * Customer_Week_2[-1:-2])
#>   First_name Last_name Factor_1 Factor_2 Factor_3
#> 1       John   Jackson        6    0.255        0
#> 2       Mary     Smith       35    0.325        2
#> 3      David  Williams        8    0.540        6
#> 4       Paul Zimmerman       63    0.300       12
```

Or you can be more verbose but maybe more flexible, and eshape to a long data frame, then do a grouped operation to summarize products for each person and factor. Starting from the join you have above:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Customer_week3 <- Customer_Week_1 %>%
  left_join(Customer_Week_2, by = c("First_name", "Last_name"))
```

Make long-shaped data, separate the `Factor_1.x` into `Factor_1` and `x`, and make products as your summary calculation.

```r
products <- Customer_week3 %>%
  gather(key = factor, value = value, -First_name, -Last_name) %>%
  separate(factor, into = c("factor", "week"), sep = "\\.") %>%
  group_by(First_name, Last_name, factor) %>%
  summarise(value = prod(value))

head(products)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#> # Groups:   First_name, Last_name [2]
#>   First_name Last_name factor   value
#>   <fct>      <fct>     <chr>    <dbl>
#> 1 David      Williams  Factor_1 8    
#> 2 David      Williams  Factor_2 0.54 
#> 3 David      Williams  Factor_3 6    
#> 4 John       Jackson   Factor_1 6    
#> 5 John       Jackson   Factor_2 0.255
#> 6 John       Jackson   Factor_3 0
```

If you need to get back to a wide format, spread back.

```r
products %>%
  spread(key = factor, value = value)
#> # A tibble: 4 x 5
#> # Groups:   First_name, Last_name [16]
#>   First_name Last_name Factor_1 Factor_2 Factor_3
#>   <fct>      <fct>        <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1 David      Williams         8    0.54         6
#> 2 John       Jackson          6    0.255        0
#> 3 Mary       Smith           35    0.325        2
#> 4 Paul       Zimmerman       63    0.3         12
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to @camille's reshaping, but in data.table (and disregarding Customer_week3):

```
library(data.table)

# long format
long = rbindlist(list(Customer_Week_1, Customer_Week_2), id=TRUE)

# aggregate
long[, lapply(.SD, prod), by=.(First_name, Last_name), .SDcols=patterns("^Factor")]

   First_name Last_name Factor_1 Factor_2 Factor_3
1:       John   Jackson        6    0.255        0
2:       Mary     Smith       35    0.325        2
3:      David  Williams        8    0.540        6
4:       Paul Zimmerman       63    0.300       12
```

Going longer (again as seen in @camille's answer) might also make sense, so as to avoid repeatedly fiddling with names of Factor_* columns:

```
longer = melt(long, meas=patterns("^Factor")) # analogous to gather
longer[, .(value = prod(value)), by=.(First_name, Last_name, variable)]
```